# How to export data to Excel template, retaining VBA code and data validation, using PHP?

Tags: php, excel, vba, export, phpexcel

I need to export data to an Excel template that contains VBA code and data validation in PHP.

I tried using PHPExcel library but it is removing the VBA code and data validations from the template.

I tried using PHPReport library, didn't get proper solution.

The template contains multiple worksheets and they are interdependent.
E.g.: Worksheet 1 contains employee data, then worksheet 2 contains salary with respect to employee name.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent a great deal of time working on this problem, and the problem of memory consumption for large data sets. All of the PHP libs I have found keep all of the cells in memory, which is not viable for anything more than a small sheet.

What I ended up doing was writing a set of Java utilities using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) and packaged them with [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) so I can call them from PHP. This will allow you to create a new workbook based upon a template, keeping the macros intact. You can also use POI's streaming API, so you can handle massive data sets without crashing your server.

If you have Java chops, I highly recommend going this route, it's really the only way to do brain surgery on Excel files from PHP.

If you have any questions about how to do this or would like some example code, I'll be glad to help.